# Git error: pathspec 'directoryname' did not match any file(s) known to git. How to solve?

Tags: git

I'm working with a Magento site and anytime I do a `git commit *` from the application root, the commit fails and prints the following error:

```
error: pathspec 'media' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

There is a `media` directory in the root of the site and it has been ignored.  The global `.gitignore` file has the following line:

```
/media
```

Any ideas how to eliminate this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command is

```
git commit -a
```

This commits all changes to files that are under source control.  From the git help commit user help:

```
   -a, --all
       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.
```